# Beginner Query - Magento Theme Not Falling Back?

Tags: magento-1.9, package, theme-fallback

I'm attempting to build a custom package and theme using the Magento guide at: magento.com/sites/default/files/MagentoDesignGuide.pdf

One of the fundamental points it makes at the beginning is that if any of the files are missing, Magento will always fall back to the default files.

I made a new package folder named **newpackage** against `app/design/frontend` and the same against `skin/frontend` and added "default" as sub-directories (also added template, layout, css, js etc. to relevant folders as advised):

So this is all I have, a few empty folders ready to play with. When I changed the **Current Package Name** against my store view, it seems to have broken the theme:

Could anybody please let me know why my package isn't falling back to the default files when it realises that the templates/css etc. is missing? As this looks nothing like it did before I enabled this package. Thank you so much for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I know for design fall back is that .

1) it will check files and folder in your `yourpackage/yourtheme`.

2) after that it will check in `yourpackage/default`

3) and at last `base/default` .

This how its work if you add and exception then it will check in that exception case

Other than this no other theme will call and also not that `default/default` theme or `rwd/default` theme is not call by default.

Hope this will help you understand how design fallback works

Comment: You are always welcome :)